# Finish process first before jumping to another one in express

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I want my app to finish the first process before executing another. How can I do it here?

```
//first
new Imagemin()
.src('./'+req.file.path)
.dest('./compressed/')
.use(Imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 3}))
.run(function (err, files) {
    //console.log(files[0]);}
});

//this is next
var compress = fs.statSync('./compressed/'+req.file.filename);

console.log(req.file);
res.json({
    filename: req.file.filename,
    originalsize: req.file.size,
    compressedsize: compress["size"]
});
```

I am getting error since the first process is a bit slow coz it's optimizing image. So i need to make sure it is finished before executing code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the second part in the callback function.
e.g.

```
new Imagemin()
.src('./'+req.file.path)
.dest('./compressed/')
.use(Imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 3}))
.run(function (err, files) {
    //console.log(files[0]);}
    doNext();
});

function doNext() {
  var compress = fs.statSync('./compressed/'+req.file.filename);

  console.log(req.file);
  res.json({
      filename: req.file.filename,
      originalsize: req.file.size,
      compressedsize: compress["size"]
  });
}
```